# How to "force" an Crystal Reports optional parameter to not need a value

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that has an optional parameter called Supplier Name.

My Selection Expert logic is set up like this:

**if hasvalue({?Supplier Name}) then
{q_InStockItems_ByUnitSize_vw.primary_supplier_id} = {?Supplier Name}
else
true

So if no value is entered in the optional parameter, all the records are returned.

I am populating the parameter via C# using the following line of code:
 InventoryReport.SetParameterValue("Supplier Name", SupplierID);

The problem I am experiencing is that I want to have the ability to not programmatically pass a value to the optional parameter, so all the records are returned.
[image]
If I don't specifically provide a value to the optional parameter, Crystal Reports opens the report, and displays the parameter entry window.

I can hit ok and all the records get displayed, but I'm hoping there is some way to skip over the above step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Optional Parameters when running Crystal Reports 2011 report from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055997/handling-optional-parameters-when-running-crystal-reports-2011-report-from-c-sha)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if IsNull({?Supplier Name}) then true;

else {q_InStockItems_ByUnitSize_vw.primary_supplier_id} = {?Supplier Name};